# how to make rollover time as integral point in python timerotatingfilehandler

Tags: python, logging

The initial rollover time of python timerotatingfilehandler is the lastest file modification time. It is not always at an integral point. For example, when I set the parameter `when='H'`, how to make the rollover time at the integral point, like 14:00:00 instead of 14:15:30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by manually setting the initial rolloverAt attribute. So when it's 14:15 you tell the handler to rollover at 15:00, and from there it will just increment by an hour every further rollover.

```py
from logging import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from datetime import datetime

handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('file.log', when='H')
last_full_hour = datetime.now().replace(minute=0, second=0).timestamp()
handler.rolloverAt = last_full_hour + handler.interval # 3600 would work too
```